# How to use Stash to avoid embedded templates

Tags: stash

I'm excited about being able to use Stash to avoid having to use series of embedded templates, but can't figure out how to make it work. The code below generates the variable 'course' and uses it in the second loop. The variable, {exp:stash:course} and {exp:stash:get name="course"}, work fine by themselves, outside of the second loop, but using the search parameter within the loop there is nothing. I should be able to view {exp:stash:cats}, which is in the embedded template.

I've tried using various parameters to fix the problem such as 'save', 'cache', 
'trim', 'parse tags', and others. I think this must be a parse order issue.

Thanks,

Geoff

```
{embed="site/test1"}

{exp:stash:set name="course" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="topic" url_title="{segment_2}"}
    {url_title}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:set name="cats" trim="yes"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="explore" search:coursename="{exp:stash:course}"}
{title}
<br />
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Wow, that was complicated and a waste of time but I figured it out through a lot of research and trial and error. I don't know if it's going to be worth continuing if such simple tasks are so complex. Anyway, here's the working code:

```
{embed="site/test1"}

{exp:channel:entries channel="topic" dynamic="no"  limit="1" url_title="spirituality"}
  {exp:stash:set name="my_test" parse_tags="yes"}{title}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:stash:set name="cats"}
  {exp:stash:parse process="end"}
      {exp:channel:entries channel="explore" dynamic="no" parse="inward" search:coursename="{stash:my_test}"}
      {title}<br />
      {/exp:channel:entries}
  {/exp:stash:parse} 
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Comment: Add `parse=inward` to your 2nd exp:channel entry ?

Comment: & you also need `parse_variables=yes ` on the 2nd stash set

Comment: Oops, `parse_tags`

Comment: Thanks, I tried adding those variables including parse="inward" but it's still not working. I would think that this is a very common problem - so I wonder if there is some kind of basic, standard solution?

Comment: All right, I found a post with more information and the second exp:channel entry is now parsing the first stash - but I haven't figured out how to set the second variable so it can be passed on to the embedded template. Here is what I have now:

Comment: {embed="site/test1"}

{exp:channel:entries channel="topic" dynamic="no"  limit="1" url_title="spirituality"}
{exp:stash:set name="my_test" output="yes" parse_tags="yes"}{title}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="explore" dynamic="no" search:coursename="{stash:my_test}" parse="inward"}
{exp:stash:set name="cats"}{title}<br />{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}

Comment: Google is your friend: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/7166